# ByteBuffer to String in Java

Tags: java, bytebuffer

I have this line of code

```
String s = new String(m_buffer.array());
```

where buffer is a ByteBuffer.

Is there a way to convert a bytebuffer to string without allocating a new String and/or involve copying of array of char? (ie, is there a way to just point the String's char[] value to the ByteBuffer's byte[] hb safely?)

Thanks

Comment: First of all `byte[]` isn't `char[]`, and secondly no. You should be more worried about creating strings from bytes without specifying the encoding. A very good way to end up writing code that breaks as soon as your default encoding changes.

Comment: Strings are immutable in Java, so that's another reason why this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A way to convert a ByteBuffer to a String would be to use a Charset to decode the bytes:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

ByteBuffer m_buffer = ...;

String text = charset.decode(m_buffer).toString();
```

The decoding creates a `CharBuffer` which you can conveniently convert to a `String`. You can reuse the `CharSet` and it is threadsafe. I wouldn't worry too much about performance (re "fastest way") unless you have really a problem in that area. A general advice, when you want to use ByteBuffer, do the to-String conversion as late as possible, and only when the String is needed.

As 14jbella mentioned, Strings are immutable. There is no way of creating a String from an array (char or byte) that does not include copying the data because arrays are mutable. So no, there is no way to do it without copying.

Further you should take into consideration, that `m_buffer.array()` returns the internal array of the `ByteBuffer`, which may be much more than the actual data stored in the buffer. Creating a String from that array might lead to a potentially huge memory allocation, because the data gets copied into a new array. For example if you're using a 256 MB ByteBuffer somewhere in your code, and you get a `slice()` of 32 bytes named `m_buffer` from that buffer to convert to a String, your invocation of `new String(m_buffer.array())` would allocate a new byte array of the size of the original, backing byte array, which is 256 MB, which is probably not that fast, if it requires a GC.

Btw. `new String(byte[])` internally uses a `CharSet` decoder on a `ByteBuffer` wrapped around your input byte array.

Answer (score 4):

Java's `String` class is immutable. In order to maintain this guarantee, `String` has to have its own reference to the `char[]` backing it, and nobody else may have that reference. If it were to share an array with the `ByteBuffer`, the `String` class could not guarantee that it would not be modified. In addition, `char`, and `byte` are not the same in Java.

Comment: Thanks guys. So is my way of doing it the "fastest way" to convert a bytebuffer to string? (like would StringBuilder help?)